# datatime o datatimeoffset ¿cómo y cuándo usarlo?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

Estuve probando usar `datetime` en `SQL-Server` luego de usar `datetimeoffset` para guardar fechas y hora como me enseñaron, pero estuve pensando en si hay alguna forma de reducir este código y mantener el mismo resultado.

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetimeoffset,GETDATE()) AS 'DATETIMEOFFSET'
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(datetimeoffset,GETDATE())) AS 'DATETIME'
```

Probé esto y me entrega el mismo resultado pero no sé si es correcto hacerlo en mis proyectos o es que bajo ciertas condiciones tendré algún resultado diferente...

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, GETDATE()) AS 'DATETIME 2'
```

Comment: Déjanos saber si alguna de las respuestas solucionó tu problema marcándola con el check y con el upvote del lado izquierdo. En caso contrario, deja un comentario para tratar de darte otras soluciones.

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes saber que cualquier columna de una tabla definida como `DateTime` se grabara de la siguiente forma : `2023-03-30 22:08:00.000`.

Ahora los tipos de fecha van depender de las necesidades de tu sistema, lo mas probable que el 98% de las columnas de tipo fecha serán definidas como `DateTime`.

```
Eje.:
CREATE TABLE TablaEje (
    Id       int identity (1, 1) not null,
    Nombre   varchar(50),
    FechaNac DateTime,
    Direccion varchar(128)
)

Insert into TablaEje values ('Sergio Canales Urra', '1978-05-31T00:00:00.000', 'Avenida San Martin 2630')
```

Prueba este ejemplo para que veas como SqlServer graba el campo "FechaNac".

Answer (score 0):

El tipo de inserción depende de cómo necesitas consultar los datos posteriormente...

Los formatos de fecha aceptados por `SQl-Server` son los siguientes:

| Tipo de dato | Formato |
| --- | --- |
| Time | hh:mm:ss[.nnnnnnn] |
| Date | YYYY-MM-DD |
| SmallDateTime | YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss |
| DateTime | YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss[.nnn] |
| DateTime2 | YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss[.nnnnnnn] |
| DateTimeOffset | YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss[.nnnnnnn] [+/-]hh:mm |

Después de definir el formato de inserción, puedes usar las diferentes funciones de `SQL-Server` para consultar las fechas y darle el formato de salida que requieras.

Por ejemplo, de las que mas uso son:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAMPO_FECHA, 120) AS FECHA
--Retorna 2023-03-30

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), CAMPO_FECHA, 120) AS FECHA_HORA
--Retorna 2023-03-30 21:50:28

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAMPO_FECHA, 108) AS FECHA
--Retorna 21:50:28
```

Existen las funciones `CAST` y `CONVERT` con múltiples opciones. Puedes consultar los diferentes formatos en [sqlshack](https://www.sqlshack.com/es/funciones-y-formatos-de-sql-convert-date/), en la pagina oficial de [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) o en muchos otros recursos que encuentras fácilmente con Google.